# Search a range of IPs instead of a list

Tags: script, vbscript

Instead of this looking at a file for a list of IPs, I want to have it look at a range. The range needs to be as large as a class C. Can some one help me edit the code below to achieve this? I am trying to search 10.0.0.0 with a subnet mask of 255.255.0.0.

```
' NetworkFindInfo.vbs - Windows Logon Script.
' VBScript - Look up a computers info. 
' Author Chris Collins
' Version 1 - July 2018
' ----------------------------------------------------------' 

Option Explicit

Const wbemFlagReturnImmediately = &h10
Const wbemFlagForwardOnly = &h20

Const PATH_TO_INPUT = "C:\Users\ccollins\Desktop\NetworkFindingInfo\ComputerList.txt"
Const PATH_TO_OUTPUT = "C:\Users\ccollins\Desktop\NetworkFindingInfo\ComputerInfo.csv"

Dim fso
Set fso = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Dim shl
Set shl = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Dim input
Set input = fso.OpenTextFile(PATH_TO_INPUT)

Dim output
Set output = fso.CreateTextFile(PATH_TO_OUTPUT, True)

output.WriteLine "Hostname,Computer Name,Domain,Serial Number,Make,Model,BIOS Version,Operating System,CPU,Memory (MB),Disk Drives,MAC Address"

Dim wmiService
Dim wmiResults

Dim hostname
Dim computername
Dim domain
Dim make
Dim model
Dim biosversion
Dim operatingSystem
Dim serialNumber
Dim cpu
Dim memory
Dim drives
Dim mac

Dim line
Dim exec
Dim pingResults
While Not input.AtEndOfStream
line = input.ReadLine
hostname = ""
computername = ""
domain = ""
make = ""
model = ""
biosversion = ""
operatingSystem = ""
serialNumber = ""
cpu = ""
memory = ""
drives = ""
mac = ""

Set exec = shl.Exec("ping -n 2 -w 1000 " & line)
pingResults = LCase(exec.StdOut.ReadAll)

If InStr(pingResults, "reply from") Then
On Error Resume Next

Set wmiService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & line & "\root\CIMV2")

If Not Err.Number = 0 Then
output.WriteLine line & ",Error: " & Err.Description
On Error GoTo 0
Else
On Error GoTo 0
hostname = line

Set wmiResults = wmiService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_BIOS", "WQL", wbemFlagReturnImmediately + wbemFlagForwardOnly)

Dim item
For Each item In wmiResults
serialNumber = Trim(item.SerialNumber)
biosversion = Trim(item.SMBIOSBIOSVersion)
Next

Set wmiResults = wmiService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_ComputerSystem", "WQL", wbemFlagReturnImmediately + wbemFlagForwardOnly)

For Each item In wmiResults
make = Trim(item.Manufacturer)
model = Trim(item.Model)
computername = Trim(item.Name)
domain = Trim(item.Domain)
Next

Set wmiResults = wmiService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem", "WQL", wbemFlagReturnImmediately + wbemFlagForwardOnly)

For Each item In wmiResults
operatingSystem = Trim(item.Name)
operatingSystem = Split(operatingSystem, "|")(0)
memory = Round(Trim(item.TotalVisibleMemorySize) / 1024, 2)
Next

Set wmiResults = wmiService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Processor", "WQL", wbemFlagReturnImmediately + wbemFlagForwardOnly)

For Each item In wmiResults
cpu = Trim(item.Name)
Next

Set wmiResults = wmiService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapter WHERE PhysicalAdapter = 1", "WQL", wbemFlagReturnImmediately + wbemFlagForwardOnly)

For Each item In wmiResults
mac = Trim(item.MACAddress)
Next

Set wmiResults = wmiService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_LogicalDisk WHERE DriveType=3", "WQL", wbemFlagReturnImmediately + wbemFlagForwardOnly)

For Each item In wmiResults
drives = drives & Trim(item.DeviceID) & " " & Round(Trim(item.Size) / (1024^2), 2) & ";"
Next

output.WriteLine hostname & "," & computername & "," & domain & "," & serialNumber & "," & make & "," & model & "," & biosversion & "," & operatingSystem & "," & cpu & "," & memory & "," & drives & "," & mac
End If
Else
output.WriteLine line & ",No Response"
End If
Wend

output.Close
input.Close

Set wmiService = Nothing
Set wmiresults = Nothing

Msgbox("Done Collecting Data")
```

As an addition there are certain IPs on my network that this code just stops at. Is there a way to keep it running?

Comment: Essential this script looks at a list of IPs and if it is a computer returns WMI information, and if its not it tells me the status of the IP. Am trying to gather information on my network. Right now the list file is just every IP in my subnets but I want to program it in.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how big/flexible your range needs to be.

In the simplest form

```
baseIP="10.10."

for a=0 to 255
  for b=0 to 255

IP=baseIP&a&"."&b

<\Your code here>

  next b
next a
```

More later

Something resembling a subnet search

```
main

sub main

Dim WshShell, oExec
Dim x

Set wshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set objInputFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("c:\scripts\computers.txt",1)

Do until objInputFile.AtEndofStream
userIP = objInputFile.ReadLine


numBits=Mid(userIP,instr(1,userIP,"/")+1,3)
numIP=CDbl(2^(32-mid(userIP,instr(1,userIP,"/")+1,3)))
ip=Mid(userIP,1,instr(1,userIP,"/")-1)

a=Split(ip,".")
'Darn vbscript has signed numbers so -2 billion to pos 2 billion
' and ip's go 0 to 4 billion
'lame work around
If a(0)>127 Then offset=128 Else offset=0
a(0)=a(0)-offset

ipnum=CDbl((a(0)*256^3)+(a(1)*256^2)+(a(2)*256)+a(3))
ipEnd=CDbl(ipnum+numIP)

For x=ipnum To ipEnd

grab=Hex(x)
grab2=Mid("00000000"&grab,Len(grab)+1,8)

a=CLng("&h"&Mid(grab2,1,2))+offset
b=CLng("&h"&Mid(grab2,3,2))
c=CLng("&h"&Mid(grab2,5,2))
d=CLng("&h"&Mid(grab2,7,2))

newip=a&"."&b&"."&c&"."&d
WScript.echo "newip:"&newip

inventory(newip)
Next 

Loop

end sub
```

Start and end ip addresses

```
begIP="10.10.3.1"
endIP="10.10.10.1"

a=Split(begIP,".")
b=Split(endIP,".")
'Darn vbscript has signed numbers so -2 billion to pos 2 billion
' and ip's go 0 to 4 billion
'lame work around
If a(0)>127 Then offset=128 Else offset=0
a(0)=a(0)-offset
b(0)=b(0)-offset
ipnum=CDbl((a(0)*256^3)+(a(1)*256^2)+(a(2)*256)+a(3))

ipEnd=CDbl((b(0)*256^3)+(b(1)*256^2)+(b(2)*256)+b(3))

For x=ipnum To ipEnd

grab=Hex(x)
grab2=Mid("00000000"&grab,Len(grab)+1,8)

a=CLng("&h"&Mid(grab2,1,2))+offset
b=CLng("&h"&Mid(grab2,3,2))
c=CLng("&h"&Mid(grab2,5,2))
d=CLng("&h"&Mid(grab2,7,2))

newip=a&"."&b&"."&c&"."&d
WScript.echo "newip:"&newip
inventory(newip)

Next 
end sub
```

Comment: I like the second option, how would I fit that into my code above?

Comment: Turn the bulk of your code into a function called inventory.  The 3rd last line of my code will call your inventory function.  At the beginning of my code you would open your file and place a while <> EOF loop around it. Reading 1 line of input from your file placing the result in $baseIP.  Assuming your file is formatted that way.